# Banner not visible after plugin publishing

Tags: plugins, svn

I published a first small plugin on wordpress.org.
I tried to follow all steps but the banner does not appear.

1. I named my banner like this : banner-772×250.jpg
2. I commit with svn on the `assets` folder on the root

Notice : The icon is visible.

what could be the problem ?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind, did you double check the image actually is 772x250 pixels? And that it is recognized as a real JPG (i.e. it's not another file type with ".jpg" erroneously added)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was :

I generated images with Illustrator, I got this before saving the image :

[image]

translation : "Some file names contains caracters no latin. These names won´t be incompativél with servers and Web browsers"

The problem was, I copied the name from a Web page and that created a non latin caracter.

When I named manually banners with the `x` key, The name files were different, look at this :
[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to specify the image  (icon) that is shown on the plugin's page, then try naming the image file icon-128x128.png/jpg .

Banner images are

```
Normal Banner: banner-772x250.(jpg|png)
Normal Banner (RTL): banner-772x250-rtl.(jpg|png)
High-DPI (Retina): banner-1544x500.(jpg|png)
High-DPI (Retina RTL): banner-1544x500-rtl.(jpg|png)
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-assets/

If the banner (or icon, different things, I know) doesn't show up on the plugin listing page, perhaps the updated info hasn't been synced.

You could try changing the version number in the plugin and readme to see if that will update things. Don't know if just uploading/svn-sync the assets folder will change things on the plugin settings page.

**Added**

Also, this post seems to indicate that you need two versions of your banner image to support retina displays:

```
banner-772×250.png
banner-1544×500.png
```

https://torquemag.io/2014/09/plugin-developers-manage-image-assets/

Comment: I don´t understand your answer. My problem is about the banner, not the icon. And as I said, I called my banner file `banner-772×250.jpg`. So... I know the documentation.

Comment: See info added to the answer, which mentions icons and banners (as did the original answer).

Comment: So my answer, while containing correct information, was not the answer to your problem - which was caused by improper naming of the files (using non-ASCII characters). If you have the correct answer, then you should enter it as the answer, marking it correct (not putting the solution in your question). Downvote of my answer that contains correct information is not needed.

Comment: Yes, the solution was in your answer. It´s correct for a robot but I am a human. For a computer the "x" was not the "x" I supposed to. For my eyes, it was difficult to see the difference. So your answer does not help me. The most important here is a developper which has got this kind of weird error can resolve it quickly, Most of them would have read the documentation without seeing the matter.